# Finding a basis for $\ker T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

given a linear map $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which exists:

$$T(x, y, z, w) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right)$$

Find a basis for $\ker T$.

My attempt:
$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}
x+y+z+w\\
2x -z +w 
\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} 
0 \\ 
0 
\end{array}\right)
$

Let $z \triangleq s, \ w \triangleq t$

preforming calculations, I have:

$$ \operatorname{Ker} T =  \operatorname{sp} \left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\-3\\2\\0\end{array}\right),\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\\-2\end{array}\right)\right\} $$

Is this correct?

Comment: yes, it's correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good thing about this exercise is that you can check yourself.

Denote the vectors you found as $v,w$. If $Tv=Tw=0$ and $v$ and $w$ are independent, then you found a basis for $kerT$.

Comment: Well, somewhere in there you also have to show that the nullity is 2, but that’s quite simple in this case.

Comment: @amd Of course. I took that for granted.